Finding “ghost” fonts in PowerPoint to replace them
Sometimes it happens that when saving a PowerPoint file, it displays a message saying that
Some of your fonts cannot be saved with the presentation.
Cannot be saved: (font name)
Reason: Font Not Available

The problem is that even if you use Replace Fonts... to replace the missing font with one of those installed on the system, the issue persists. It's as if the font is somewhere PowerPoint is unable to apply the replacement. Not only that: this “somewhere” is in a place where manually searching for the text element containing the font is unsuccessful. Basically, it's unclear where the font is.
Is there a way, perhaps using VBA, to find exactly where the font in question is and replace it with another?

This question is similar to: How to deal with missing fonts when saving PowerPoint 365 presentation. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You can write code that peers into the PPTX file (a zip file actually) and modifies the XML inside to change fonts, but it's not a simple task. You might instead want to try the free demo of SlideWise from Neuxpower (https://neuxpower.com/slidewise-powerpoint-add-in#faq-free) Even after the demo period ends, it'll still point you at the shapes that use the problem fonts so you can choose a different font.
